# How to implement IOCTL_REDIR_QUERY_PATH in filesystem driver?

Tags: windows, filesystems, device-driver, unc

I'm making a network redirector and would like to support UNC.
To support UNC I should implement `IOCTL_REDIR_QUERY_PATH`. I have read [the document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but can't understand what `LengthAccepted` means.
Suppose my unc name is `\\a\b` and receive the control code with the path string `\a\b\c.txt`. Then what should I fill the `LengthAccepted` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the anwser from osronline.com
Here is the link. http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=222210